# In Windows 10, can I find out what specifically BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service) is downloading?

Tags: windows-10

I am using WIFI with a metered connection, which means Microsoft Updates will not automatically download. However, recently I've noticed via Task Manager that BITS is running and downloading something when I start my computer. This has not happened before on a metered connection, so I am trying to find out what BITS is trying to download. (Microsoft Update says I am up to date, although I noticed it is not always accurate about this.)

I am not looking for information on how to disable BITS. I just what to know what it is downloading, not only out of curiosity but in case malware might be involved.

I uninstalled Microsoft Office years ago, so this should not be a factor. I looked through Task Scheduler and found nothing obvious that would invoke BITS. System Startup does include "Intel Driver & Support Assistant" and "SecurityHealth", which possibly could call on BITS, but I have never noticed them downloading anything before.

Comment: look up bitsadmin.  There is also a few PS comandlets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way that I know of to know what BITS is downloading, but if you wish
to find out what outside connections has your computer, this is possible.
Use the free utility
[TCPView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview)
to view all connections in real time. New connections will display briefly
highlighted in yellow.

Another tracing method is detailed in the article
[How to Track Internet Activity for Free Using Windows Firewall Log](https://www.maketecheasier.com/track-internet-activity-windows-firewall-log/),
although you may find yourself overwhelmed with the number of details.

As BITS only serves higher-level applications, a simple way to find out which
applications are using too much network time, is by using the Task Manager.
The "App history" tab contains all the activity on the computer for the
last 30 days. You may click the "Network" column to sort all applications
in order of network usage.

[image]